# How can I serve in angular 7 application several locales at the same time?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, angular-i18n

While developing app I would like to switch between several locales which my app supports. So I need to serve an app with all these locales, but I could not find a way of doing it.

Is it possible to do what I want with/without any hacks?

**EDIT:** it worth to mention, that I'm using i18n approach suggested by this page: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Angular does not support a dynamic translation system. You need to generate one static build for each locale you want in your application, as stated in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n):

> You need to build and deploy a separate version of the app for each supported language.

One solution (for me, better than the Angular approach), is using the [`ngx-translate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core) library ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)). It's worth mentioning that the creator of the library (ocombe) is now working with the Angular team building the new i18n system based on the Ivy Renderer.

Where I work we started a very big project using the Angular i18n system because of the `xliff` standard format for translators, but after 6 months we decided to leave it because of build times (imagine doing 10 builds in prod mode in a big project... It can takes about 30min to build). Another problem we have is that Angular translation system does not support translations in strings with parameters, something very common...